# Terminal troubleshoot

Tags: terminal

Whenever I try to write something in vs terminal it stop and than show unhandel exception threw and the pop windows come and show unknown software cause exception.
I tried to run pycharm terminal it's same .
Anyone know to to fix it

I want there terminal start running and work people

Comment: (1) You don't say what exception. (2)  You don't say what terminal. (3) You don't say what OS. (4) Your question is not about programming, and therefore not suitable for Stackoverflow. Ask this on [su], but with that meager information, nobody will help you there either.